# How do I prevent shattering of glass?

Tags: temperature

I am not an expert of physics, instead I am more good at chemistry.

I just wanted to ask that how do I prevent shattering of glasses on sudden large temperature changes?

Sometimes, when I have to cool hot test tubes rapidly, the test tubes break down when I place them in water for cooling.

Is there any way to prevent it?

Comment: You mean besides taking hot (fragile) things and putting them in cold water?

Comment: yeah! But also glass should not break

Comment: Why should glass not break?

Comment: read the question again pls.!!

Comment: Oops, I forgot "not" in my first comment. It should have read "You mean besides **not** taking hot (fragile) things and putting them in cold water?"

Comment: In any event, [thermal shock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermal_shock) is likely going to show up each time you try it. The best you can do is to not use glass but some other material that can handle the temperature shift (ceramic might, but not 100% sure).

Comment: There are certain types of glasses with very low expansion coefficients that are not as susceptible to thermal shock, usually used in high end optics.  Borosilicate Glass is one such type of glass.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Pyrex, Vycor, fused silica - in that order.

Comment: Also try thicker walled test tubes. Sometimes these problems are solved just by finding the right manufacturer.

Comment: Surely thinner walled test tubes? It's the temperature difference across the walls that causes the failure.